# How to save selected tableView cell into array in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an tableview which list static array values. Multiple selection can be done in tableview. I am trying to show an UIView when selecting cell and hide none of the cell is selected, Also i want save selected cell values into an array, so that i can able to post data to api calls.

Here is my code:

```
 //UIView which i want to show (when cell is selected) and hide (when cell is not selected)
    @IBOutlet weak var rejAppView: UIView!

//tableView

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sampleData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prCell", for: indexPath) as! PrListCellTableViewCell

    let data = sampleData[indexPath.row]
    print("req|:\(String(describing: data.req))")
    cell.reqLbl.text = data.req

    let ChecktapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.checktapBtnAction(_:)))
    cell.tickImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tickImageView.addGestureRecognizer(ChecktapGesture)
    cell.tickImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let passReqtapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.passReqtapBtnAction(_:)))
    cell.passReqNo.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.passReqNo.addGestureRecognizer(passReqtapGesture)
    cell.passReqNo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true



    return cell
}
```

For multiple selection i have added tap gesture for imageView:

here is the code mutiple selection and UIVIiew show/hide:

```
    @objc func checktapBtnAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("\(String(describing: sender.view?.tag)) Tapped")


    guard let rowIndexPath = sender.view?.tag else {
        return
    }



    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndexPath, section: 0)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! PrListCellTableViewCell

 //        if cell.checked == true {
 //
 //            self.rejAppView.isHidden = true
 // . 
 //
//        } else if cell.checked == false {

//            self.rejAppView.isHidden = false
//        }



    cell.checked = !cell.checked
    print("cell type\(String(describing: cell.checked))")

   }
```

Here is my tableView cell code:

```
       @IBOutlet weak var tickImageView: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    checked = false

}

var checked: Bool! {
    didSet {
        if (self.checked == true) {
            self.tickImageView.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
        }else{
            self.tickImageView.image = UIImage(named: "untick")
        }
    }
}
```

My issue i can able to show rejAppView (UIView) when selecting single/multiple cell but when unselecting all the cell rejAppView (UIView) is not hided also i could not able store selected value into an array.
Any help much appreciated pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define array of indexPath or of integer in which you add indexPath/ indexPath.row if cell selected. and remove that object on unselecting cell.

based on that array you can hide view

```
var array = [IndexPath]()


@objc func checktapBtnAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
print("\(String(describing: sender.view?.tag)) Tapped")


guard let rowIndexPath = sender.view?.tag else {
    return
}
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndexPath, section: 0)


cell.checked = !cell.checked
print("cell type\(String(describing: cell.checked))")

if cell.checked {
    array.append(indexPath)
} else {
    let index = array.index(of: indexPath)
    array.remove(at: index)
}

if array.count == 0 {
    self.rejAppView.isHidden = true
} else {
    self.rejAppView.isHidden = false
}
}
```